# Persisting loged-in status using realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just began using RealmSwift and wanted to create a login page where the logged-in status is persisted,
I wrote the following code to save the password and regID

```
func saveData(){
    let obj=RealmObjects()
    obj.pass=passwordTextField.text!
    obj.reg=registrationTextField.text!
    try! realm.write{
    realm.add(obj) }
```

and the object class is :

```
class RealmObjects:Object{
@objc dynamic var pass = ""
@objc dynamic var reg = ""
```

now how should i implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

Realm automatically persists the login status of the users that are currently logged in, so there should be no reason for you to persist them separately.

You can get the list of current active users with `SyncUser.all`. See the [Working with users](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#working-with-users) part of the documentation for details.